# How would I create a save file for my to-do list?

Tags: javascript, node.js

So I have a to-do list and I have setup a basic server with node. I have stored all the data in the back-end, how would I save it to a file and read it when the page is loaded?

Comment: Can you post your code, or a link to it on pastebin/jsfiddle etc? Also, what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To create a file with Node.js you can use this function:

```
fs.writeFile('message.txt', 'Hello', (err) => {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log('The file has been saved!');
});
```

To read from the file you would use:

```
fs.readFile('/etc/passwd', (err, data) => {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log(data);
});
```

There may be other ways to acomplish this but these are the most common. More details in the documentation: https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html